# Converting Multiple Search Hits into Multiple Cursors in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

In VSCode, I'd like to be able to transform multiple search hits into multiple cursor locations.

In VSCode, I'd like to find all instance of a term (e.g., "fred") and insert a cursor at each location where the term appears.  Here, the particular interest is using alt-arrow to reposition the lines in the code.  I'm aware that I can alt-shift-I to turn a selection into multiple line cursors but I haven't gotten this too work with the search/replace box.  (I could also write a  regex expression to do this, but it would be more straightforward with a multiple cursor.)

In the sample below, the pipe | character represents an insertion point.  What I want to do is use the find command to locate all the instances of "fred" and then have a cursor appear at the fred locations.  E.g.,

```
var first = {
  name: fred|,
  location: NJ
};
var second = {
  name: fred|,
  location: CT
};
var thrid = {
  name: jane,
  location: OH
}
var fourth = {
  name: fred|,
  location: WY
}
```

Comment: You can always do find and replace all using `ctrl + shift + f`

Comment: I know how to do this manually, but depending on file size it can be a pain. Select keyword and then Ctrl / Command + D. You'll advance through every appearance of the keyword and get a cursor set at its end.

Comment: @sanketd617, Alex D., thanks, but these techniques require moving each line individually, which is tedious when you're dealing with 160 lines that need to be relocated...

Comment: @sanketd617 -- that technique doesn't work with ctrl-f searches.  I wouldn't be surprised if there is no way to do this, so I get to write some gnarly regex.